# How to modify a pre-trained tensorflow model without the source code?

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to modify a pre-trained model(to be specific, the ssdlit-mobilenetv2 in the tensorflow detection zoo).
What I want to do is to extract the ouput of one layer, do some modification to the output, then feed it back and continue to run the model. 
I only got the .pb file and the ckpt files, how can I do this without the source code?

So what code should I use?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have no easy way of doing this.. Just write your own tool for your concrete modification based on existing data, than saving it again as checkpoint and continue train process from that point.

If file has the information of values, so you can change it manually, but i don't think it could be effective.

Also, as you know the name (mobilentv2) you can find the net architecture and the source codes

Comment: Actually, it should be the ssdlite+mobilenetv2, mobilenetv2 as feature extractor, not just mobilenetv2. I tried to find the source code, but I failed

Comment: This is the only file that I got, but I dont know how to use it. Is the graph generate by this file?(much different from the normal tensorflow files)https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/models/ssd_mobilenet_v2_feature_extractor.py